# Having trouble with quotes in PHP echo

Tags: php, string

I'm having trouble with my quotes on a PHP `echo`. I am not sure if it is because I am using wrong quotes /  placing them in the wrong place, or if it's because I can't set my button value to what I have (see code).

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM calender WHERE userid=?;";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
  header ('Location: ../personalcalender.php?error=sqlerror');
  exit();
}
else {
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_SESSION['Id']);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<center>" . $row['type'] ." ". $row['subject'] ." ". $row['message'] ." ".
      "<button name='changeStatus' value=\". $row['calenderid'] .\">" . $row['mystatus'] . $row['calenderid'] . "</button>";
  }
}
```

Comment: Missing `"` around `. $row['calenderid'] .`.

Comment: @gre_gor Isn't that what the ' \" ' is for after 'value='  and after '$row['calenderid']' ? I just tried what you said and still isn't working.

Comment: `\"` is part of the HTML not PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping your HTML and your PHP well-separated will prevent this sort of problem. Ideally you'd have them in separate files, but at the very least put your PHP at the top of you file, and limit anything within the HTML to display only.

Load your DB results into an array and then loop through them at the appropriate time. If you're outputting to HTML, **always** escape your data using [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://php.net/htmlspecialchars). Note the use of [alternative control structure syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) and [short echo tags](https://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php). Also, 1999 called, they want their `<center>` element back ;)

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM calender WHERE userid = ?";
$stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
if (!$stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    header ('Location: ../personalcalender.php?error=sqlerror');
    exit();
}
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['Id']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result($stmt);
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = array_map('htmlspecialchars', $row);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My page</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- some more HTML goes here -->

<?php foreach ($data as $row):?>
<div style="text-align: center"> 
    <?=$row['type']?> <?=$row['subject']?> <?=$row['message']?>
    <button name="changeStatus" value="<?=$row['calenderid']?>">
        <?=$row['mystatus']?> <?=$row['calenderid']?>
    </button>
</div>
<?php endforeach;?>
<!-- some more HTML goes here -->
</body>
</html>
```